# How to activate javascript minification?

Tags: playframework-2.0

The play documentation says that « By default, [the Assets] controller provides caching, ETag, gzip compression and JavaScript minification support. »

How can I set up play to minify the javascripts files ? It's not done in the default setting either in dev or prod mod, and the doc doesn't explain it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your javascript ressources are located in your `/app/assets/javascript` folder (so you will benefit from [Google Closure Compiler](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler)), and then, you just have to name your js file using whatevername**.min**.js

Example in a view:

```
<script src="@controllers.Assets.at("public", "javascripts/whatevername.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```